# Error 405 in class based views

Tags: python, django

I keep on getting a 405 error in my webpage for django.

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.parsers import FileUploadParser

# Create your views here.
class FileUploadView(APIView):
    #parser_classes = (FileUploadParser,)
    template_name = "list.html"
    # def put(self, request, filename, format=None):
    #     file_obj = request.data['file']
    #     # ...
    #     # do some stuff with uploaded file
    #     # ...
    #     return Response(status=204)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from rest_framework import renderers
from views import FileUploadView
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'', FileUploadView.as_view()),
]
```

**list.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Minimal Django File Upload Example</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <!-- List of uploaded documents -->
        {% if documents %}
            <ul>
                {% for document in documents %}
                    <li><a href="{{ document.docfile.url }}">{{ document.docfile.name }}</a></li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        {% else %}
            <p>No documents.</p>
        {% endif %}

        <!-- Upload form. Note enctype attribute! -->
        <form action="{% url "list" %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <p>{{ form.non_field_errors }}</p>

            <p>{{ form.docfile.label_tag }} {{ form.docfile.help_text }}</p>

            <p>
                {{ form.docfile.errors }}
                {{ form.docfile }}
            </p>

            <p><input type="submit" value="Upload"/></p>
        </form>
    </body>

</html>
```

Not sure if i need to post more of my code.

But i keep on getting a 405 error on a get request. May i know what am i doing wrong or do i need to post more information.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the "list" URL you refer to in your template? And why are you using DRF to power a normal templated view?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Its an html file that i would like to get loaded when i hit the main page

Comment: That didn't seem to have anything to do with my question. In your template you have `{% url "list" %}` as the action of the form. Where is the URL definition corresponding to that? And why are you using DRF at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to define get() method inside your class:

```
def get(self, request):
    return Response(code=200)
```

As [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/) says:

> Using the APIView class is pretty much the same as using a regular View class, as usual, the incoming request is dispatched to an appropriate handler method such as .get() or .post()

But APIView class does not have get() method, so any GET request [calls](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/views.py#L469) http_method_not_allowed() method.